# Operation of map function(x, y , z) in es6

Tags: javascript, ecmascript-6

I am a beginner es6, and this is the problem I hope to answer.

I do not understand the operation of the following code. How does the function work?

```
<script>
    var numbers = [1, 2 ,3];
    a = numbers.map(function(x, y , z){
        return x + y + z;
    });
    console.log(a); 
</script>
```

Why when printing only change element (x -'1')? And why change so?
This is the result:

`["11,2,3", "31,2,3", "51,2,3"]`

Comment: Please do not post images of code. Instead, type the code, and indent each line with 4 spaces for code-formatting (select block of code and press Ctrl+K to do such indentation).

Comment: Please don't use images, nobody will look into them. You can embed JS as a runnable snippet directly in your question.

Answer (score 2):

The syntax of `.map` is:

> .map(currentElement, index, array)

So your first iteration would look like:

> 1 + 0 + "1,2,3"

**Why `"1,2,3"`**? Because when you do arithmetic operation over Objects, it will try to convert value into number and if that fails, it will return `object.toString()`. For arrays, `.toString` will return a list of elements separated by comma.

Now **why `11,2,3` or `31,2,3`**?

That is because, plus operator(`+`) has an override to concat strings as well.

so it will return arithmetic sum of `x + y` as both are numbers and would concat it with `z` as `z` is  a string. Hence,

> 1 + 0 + "1,2,3" => 1 + "1,2,3" => "11,2,3"
>
> 2 + 1 + "1,2,3" => 3 + "1,2,3" => "31,2,3"
>
> 3 + 2 + "1,2,3" => 5 + "1,2,3" => "51,2,3"

Answer (score 0):

The code is not very useful. It works like this:

The values for x, y and z that you get in the `map` callback are:

- `x`: the value from the array element (1, then 2, then 3)
- `y`: the index where that value occurs in the array (0, then 1, then 2)
- `z`: the array itself (`[1, 2, 3]`)

If you add those three values, you get this:

- `x+y`: becomes 1+0 in the first iteration, 2+1 in the second and 3+2 in the third
- `x+y+z`: triggers a conversion of the array (`z`) to a string, which is `"1,2,3"`. Adding this to the result of `x+y` will trigger the conversion of that previous result to a string, i.e. `"1"` in the first iteration. Both are then concatenated, so in the first iteration you get `"11,2,3"`. So the 11 really is a 1 (`x+y`) followed by `1,2,3` (`z`).